# SSL configuration for domain pointing to EC2 instance

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I have my custom domain pointing to an EC2 instance.

Say mydomain.com -> [Elastic IP address for my EC2]

I would like to add SSL certificates so that I can access the site via https - `https://mydomain.com` and that should create a https connection to EC2 as well.

Now, do I need to install the certificate in both servers (domain host and EC2 instance)?

I've bought an SSL certificate from 3rd party provider and not the domain host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install the SSL on the EC2 instance.

SSL doesn't get installed at the registrar or DNS level.

Comment: Now that you said it, suddenly that makes enormous sense!